# Yacc generated C file sccsid warning supression

Tags: c, yacc, gcc-warning, rcs

I am working on a legacy project that uses yacc - 1.9 20130304.
The generated .c files contain the sccsid string (from the skeleton.c):

```
#ifndef lint
static const char <file_name>sccsid[] = "@(#)yaccpar        1.9 (Berkeley) 02/21/93";
#endif
```

When compiling with gcc -Wall I get the expected warning:

warning: '<file_name>sccsid' defined but not used [-Wunused-const-variable=]

One way that I can remove the warning is to somehow add `__attribute__((unused))` in the generated file but that would be very tedious since the project is huge and contains a lot of parser-generators with a complicated makefile structure.

Therefore I am wondering if there is a simpler way. Can I tell yacc to not generate the sccs id? Or can I instruct gcc to not warn on #ifdef lint? Or maybe some other solution?

Edit: I cannot upgrade to a newer version of byacc (that doesn't insert the sccsid) or modify skeleton.c and recompile yacc because we must ship the software with a specific version of linux and libraries due to software assurance guarantees.

Any suggestions/hints are appreciated!

Comment: How about using that variable? Surely the code has some sort of "who am I and what version am I" feature. Just modify that code to emit it somehow. Another way would be to emit it to the null device.

Comment: Can you not edit the `skeleton.c` file?  It's a nuisancy fix as you have to redo it on all machines every time the Yacc is reinstalled.  It looks like Byacc — Berkeley Yacc.  You have full rights to change the code — that makes life simpler (and the code won't change often).  Alternatively, add `-Wno-unused-const-variable` to your command line options, but it might suppress other warnings about other variables that you should pay attention to.  Can you afford to compile (the grammar files) with `-Dlint`?  It will eliminate the variable from the compiler's view.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `-Dlint` does work indeed, thanks! I tested it on one .y file and it doesn't seem to impact the compile that much.  Unfortunately `skeleton.c` is part of yacc and I cannot recompile it or use a newer version of byacc because this piece of software comes with software assurance guarantees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

There are multiple possibilities:

- You could edit the skeleton.c file? It's a nuisancy fix as you have to redo it on all machines every time Yacc is reinstalled.
- It looks like Byacc — Berkeley Yacc. You have full rights to change the code — that makes life simpler (and the code won't change often).
- Alternatively, add `-Wno-unused-const-variable` to your command-line options, but it might suppress other warnings about other variables that you should pay attention to.
- Can you afford to compile (the grammar files) with `-Dlint`? It will eliminate the variable from the compiler's view.

The last (compiling the grammars with `-Dlint`) is probably the best.  Code that is protected by `#ifndef lint` is rarely crucial to the operation of the code.  It was used to hide dubious constructs from the `lint` program back in the days when `lint` was used.  These days, with proper care in the use of headers and detailed warnings from compilers, `lint` is rarely used.